# How do I return an variable and an array from a method in php?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, methods, return

php n00b here:

I'm trying to pick a card from a deck.

The class instance is '$test_1' and the function 'pick_card' is a method of that class.

I'd like the function to return 1) the card I want, and 2) the deck, less one card.

Where am I going wrong?

```
$card, $deck = $test_1->pick_card($play_deck);

public function pick_card(&$deck)
{
    $card = $deck[0];
    echo "picked this card: " . $card . "<br />";
    array_splice($deck,0,0);
    return $card; $deck;
}
```

Comment: need to return array? `return array($card, $deck);` and retrive it with `list($card, $deck) = func();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return two variables like that in PHP.  I note that you are passing `$deck` to the function by reference, so any modifications you make to that variable will be reflected in that variable as the function operates on it.

That being said, since this is a class, you really shouldn't have to pass a variable at all, you really should have a property that stores your deck.  I would suggest something like this:

```
class card_deck {
    protected $deck = NULL;

    public function __construct() {
        // some logic to create, shuffle, and set deck array to $this->deck
    }

    public function pick_card() {
        if($this->get_card_count() < 1) {
            throw new Exception('The deck is empty.');
        }
        return array_shift($this->deck);
    }

    public function get_card_count() {
        return count($this->deck);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  How do I access $deck once the class has been instantiated?

Comment: @dwstein Personally, I would suggest adding a `get_deck()` method that would return `$this->deck`, however you could also just make `$this->deck` public and access the property directly. I personally prefer to limit access to properties from outside the class to be via getters/setters. I makes it easier to change get/set logic down the line if you don't have a bunch of places in code that directly access the property.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to return it as an array. You can use an associative array or you can use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) to break the array back out in to variables like this:

```
list($card, $deck) = $test_1->pick_card($play_deck);

public function pick_card(&$deck)
{
    $card = $deck[0];
    echo "picked this card: " . $card . "<br />";
    array_splice($deck,0,0);
    return array($card, $deck);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since you've got an object you could also use `$this`

```
class card_deck {
  public $card;
  public $deck;
  public function pick_card(&$deck) {
    $this->card = $deck[0];
    $this->deck = $deck;
    echo "picked this card: " . $this->card . "<br />";
    array_splice($this->deck,0,0);
  }
}

$test_1 = new card_deck();
//set $play_deck 
$test_1->pick_card($play_deck);

// now use
$test_1->card;
$test_1->deck;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the values you need in an associative array. I think you are familiar with arrays, as you use `deck[0]` in your `pick_card` function:

```
class Foo{
    public function pick_card(&$deck){
        $card = $deck[0];
        echo "picked this card: " . $card . "<br />";
        array_splice($deck,0,0);
        return array('card'=>$card,'deck'=>$deck);
    }
}
$test_1 = new Foo;
$deck = $test_1->pick_card($play_deck);
echo 'Card: '.$deck['card'].'<br>';
echo 'Deck: '.$deck['deck'];
```